# Rails, CanCan manage all & other roles

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user || User.new

    can :manage, :all
    can :custom_action, User, role: 'admin'
  end
end
```

and in view

```
if can? :custom_action, @user
  SHOW SOMETHING
```

this if always show "SHOW SOMETHING", don't understood why it's happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's because in your ability class, you give every user all rights.

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  @user = user || User.new

  can :manage, :all

  # When user is an admin, grant her extra privileges
  if @user.is_admin?
    can :custom_action
  end
end
```

This way, you define the abilities (by using `can`) conditionally

Comment: I this case (if can? :custom_action, @user(No admin)) must return false, but it return true. Or I some thig don't understood?

Comment: This CanCan ability config generate some thing like this. IF (any action on any object granted) || (some condition on :custom_action). So it's always True return.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user || User.new

```
can :manage, :all
cannot :custom_action, User, role: 'admin'
```

end
end

In view:

```
if can? :custom_action, @user

return 
  user = true
  admin = false
```

This is not perfect solution but it's works